# How to determine which units are being used?

Tags: c#, text, size

so I was just wondering how you go about knowing which units are used by what? does everything default to pixels, or inches or what?

For example, I have a string that I would like to put on the right side of an object. so what I thought was doing something like this:

```
string str = "this is a string";
System.Drawing.Font f = new System.Drawing.Font("Verdana",14);
System.Drawing.Size size = System.Windows.Forms.TextRenderer.MeasureText(str, f);
context.DrawText(str, new Point(790-size.Width, 1070));
```

I assume that this will take the width of the object (790) and subtract from that the length of the string, and then the string would be nice and snug up against the right side of the object....but when I do this, the string **starts** more so in the middle of the object, and there is a lot of white space between the string and the right size of the object...

For example, this is what I want:

```
                                                                           String
```

this is what I get:

```
                                                 string
```

notice in the first one, the word 'String' is right up against the right side, and in the second...it isnt

So how do I know which units are being used?

thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the width of the screen is 790?

Comment: I think Vinay has a good point.  Shouldn't you be using `this.width` to get the actual width of the form (just to be safe) instead of 790?

Comment: well...it isnt exactly the screen. I am using the 'pimped paginator' to add headers to a flow document. 790 is the width of the print on paper

Answer (score 2):

System.Windows.Forms.TextRenderer.MeasureText returns size in pixels.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.measuretext.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In WinForms, the default unit is pixels (except for e.g. font size which is in points), including the result of MeasureText.

What is context.DrawText? Why not call [Graphics.DrawString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring.aspx)?

Comment: context is a DrawingContext...I am not sure why this is used, it is from the pimpedPaginator. btw - I am using wpf